# MHX2 import in 2.79 and 2.80?

Tags: add-on

Has anyone had any luck installing the mhx2 importer under Blender 2.79 or 2.80 under **Ubuntu 18.04**?

I have followed the installation instructions correctly, and in Blender  2.79, User Preferences installs the files and shows that the mhx2 importer is installed in the "Makehuman" category.  However. when I activate the plugin, this message appears:

***This script was written Blender version 2.80.0 and might not function (correctly), though it is enabled***

No mhx2 option appears in the file Import menu.

So I tried downloading and installing the Blender 2.80 beta, then installing the mhx2 plugin, but the results were even less satisfactory.  The installation proceeds without errors, but the Preferences pane does not show that the mhx2 importer is installed at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you obtained your copy of the script from https://bitbucket.org/Diffeomorphic/mhx2-makehuman-exchange and followed the instructions there for installing it?

Comment: Yes, I have.  As I said, I followed the installation instructions correctly.  And just to make certain, I deleted the files, downloaded again and re-installed.  With the same non-results.

Comment: I had the same problem. Moreover my previous files were not read correctly. Poses were lost. Fortunately I found the previous version of the mhx2 import file in my old Blender74 directory. Now everything is OK. You can write to me bluerain @ interia.pl (omit the spaces around @) if you want to get the old mhx2 import file.

Answer (score 4):

I can now answer my own question.  The mhx2 importer DOES install and enable under Blender 2.79.  What threw me off is that A: the error message I've quoted in my original question still appears when it's enabled, and B: the mhx2  file import no longer appears in the Import/Export dialogue where I expected to find it.  Instead, it is in an (apparently) new "mhx2 runtime" tool tab.  "Import MHX2" is now found in this tool tab.

Comment: Where is this "mhx2 runtime" tool tab in the interface?

Comment: Left hand side in the main editor window, the vertical tabs next along with `Tools`, `Create` etc. Using Blender 2.79.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else having trouble finding this in 2.8, In the 3D view, press `N` to open the right hand tool tray, and find a new vertical tab on the right hand edge of said tool tray.

[image]

Comment: It's on the left-hand tool tab for me - running on a Mac.